# When an English speaker says "thousands" is the range only limited to < 10.000?

Tags: meaning-in-context

If someone says something like:

*"It is estimated that there are **thousands** of qualified digital engineers in the United States"*

do you guys assume a value between >1000 and <10.000? Or there is no such assumption in your heads and it could also mean dozens of thousands, hundreds of thousands, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, if someone says "thousands" (plural), that must mean at least two thousand.

When we generalise with expressions like "thousands" or "millions", there may be two main reasons for doing so - it could be that we just don't know the exact number, but another reason may be to exaggerate.

Here are some variations of the expression and how they may be interpreted:

- "Over a thousand" (between 1,000 - 2,000)
- "Well over a thousand" (the upper ranges of between 1,000 - 2,000)
- "Thousands" (2,000+)
- "Tens of thousands" (20,000+)
- "Hundreds of thousands" (200,000+)

When making an honest estimate, the starting point is always the number you know that there are *at least*. You wouldn't say that there were "thousands" of something unless you knew there were at least two thousand. But if you really do not know the upper limit, then saying "thousands" does not exclude the possibility that the number is in the tens of thousands, or higher.

Note that we also say "**in** the thousands", which usually does imply the estimated number is less than ten thousand. Likewise, "in the tens of thousands" would mean anything in the range *from* ten thousand up to just short of a hundred thousand.

Once you are over a million, the same rule applies - you might say "over a million" to mean less than 2 million, but once over that figure, you could legitimately say "millions".

Comment: Very interesting. I always thought "thousands" meant anything over 1000, not over 2000. Thank you.

Comment: Is "dozens of thousands" at least 24,000 (i.e. at least two dozen times at least one thousand) or is at least 48,000 (i.e. at least two dozen times at least two thousand).

Comment: @Brandin "Dozens of thousands" does not sound idiomatic at all. I wouldn't say it, I have never heard it. A dozen is of course a pre-metric measure. British people certainly do say "dozens" to suggest an indeterminate number, but using terms like tens, thousands, millions etc is so rooted in the decimal numbering system that it would be very weird to mix that with 'dozens'.

Comment: I only added that because it was mentioned in the original question. I was a bit curious about it as well, since I hadn't heard it used myself either. Yet, thanks to the magic of the Internet and search engines, I can see that there are/were people using it. I even found a book from 1968 that used it in a formal context. I wish Google gave me an option to automatically exclude all those sites like linguee and reverso that just give random sentences, which are sometimes just translations into English of idiomatic phrases in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

About all that can be said is that there are a large number.  Much more than one hundred. Almost certainly more than a thousand, probably more than two thousand, and probably less than a million.

This kind of phrase is used with intentional imprecision. It is sometimes used hyperbolically:  "She has thousands of shoes" (Even though there are only 57 pairs). It would be possible to say that "Humans have thousands of hair follicles on their bodies." (in fact about 5 million)

In the example you give, it simply means "*very many* digital engineers"  The speaker probably doesn't know the true number.  (In fact there are two million engineers, 700,000 engineering technicians, and four million computer/software engineers). You should not attempt to interpret this number literally.

Comment: I would disagree with this— there is a difference between hyperbolic and non-hyperbolic speech that cannot be distinguished solely by the use of the word “thousands.” As with any word that describes relatively large quantities, it has a tendency to be used often in hyperboles, but that certainly does not mean not to interpret the term literally or that it’s generally used imprecisely. In fact, this example’s use of the word “estimated” suggests that the speaker may not know the exact number, but is pretty sure it falls safely  in the thousands, i.e. an educated guess.

Comment: In the context of the original question, it's very unlikely that hyperbole was intended: "It is estimated that there are thousands of qualified digital engineers in the United States."

In another context, like if you tried to excuse yourself from an engagement to a friend by saying something such as: "I can't make it tonight; I've got thousands of things to do." Then yes, most likely it's hyperbole, most likely you don't in fact have 2,000+ things to do on one particular day/evening/night.